# 'which' command is incorrect

Tags: shell, sh, preloading

I have a shell script in my home directory called "echo". I added my home directory to my path, so that this echo would replace the other one.

To do this, I used: `export PATH=/home/me:$PATH`

When I do  `which echo`, it shows the one I want. `/home/me/echo`

But when I actually do something like `echo asdf` it uses the system echo.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Have you tried executing your program with ./ before it to state that it's the bash file in the current directory? If your not in that current directory you could put the path from root before the shell script.

Comment: It possible the echo script may not be in CWD, that's one good reason why you might add it to the path.

Comment: `echo`is a shell built-in command. In other words, there isn't any `echo` file at all, it's all `bash` or whatever.

Comment: `which` is not a `bash` shell built-in, which means it doesn't know about any shell built-ins that might mask an on-disk command.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario: Yes, `echo` is a shell built-in command, but there's also an external `/bin/echo` executable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`which` is an external command, so it doesn't have access to your current shell's built-in commands, functions, or aliases. In fact, at least on  my system, `/usr/bin/which` is a shell script, so you can examine it and see how it works.

If you want to know how your shell will interpret a command, use `type` rather than `which`. If you're using bash, `type -a` will print all possible meanings in order of precedence. Consult your shell's documentation for details.

For most shells, built-in commands take precedence over commands in your `$PATH`. The whole point of having a built-in `echo`, for example, is that it's faster than loading `/bin/echo` into memory.

If you want your own `echo` command to override the shell's built-in `echo`, you can define it as a shell function.

On the other hand, overriding the built-in `echo` command doesn't strike me as a good idea in the first place. If it behaves the same as the built-in `echo`, there's not much point. If it doesn't, then it could break scripts that use `echo` expecting it to work a certain way. If possible, I suggest giving your command a different way. If it's an enhanced version of `echo`, you could even call it `Echo`.

Answer (score 1):

It is likely using the shell's builtin.

If you want the one in your path you can do

> `which echo` asdf

Answer (score 1):

From [this little article that explains the rules](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/an-example-how-shell-understand-which-program-to-run-part-ii.html), here's a list in descending order of precedence:

1. Aliases
2. Shell functions
3. Shell builtin commands
4. Hash tables
5. PATH variable

`echo` is a shell builtin command (al least in [bash](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash)) and `PATH` has the lowest priority. I guess you'll need to create a function or an alias.

Comment: Functions are almost always better than aliases.